# sticker note for lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, widgets, screenlets, stickynotes

I need some sticker note or to-do-list to stick on my desktop and don't disappear when I use desktop button.
I tried KNotes , Indicator stickynotes , XPad , and even Screenlets but they all have same problem:
notes will disappear after clicking desktop button or "Super+D"

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't totally disappear<sup>*</sup>. When you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you're minimizing **all** windows including the ones created by XPad. Just hover over the items in your panel to identify the XPad ones.

[image: XPad windows minimized to the taskbar]

<sup>*</sup> In case, you don't see XPad notes in the taskbar, right-click on an XPad note and look at the Preference settings. In particular, check if "Hide all notes from the taskbar ..." and the entry below are ticked. They aren't ticked by default.

[image: XPad preferences]